# UpdatePanel Not Displaying Dynamically Added UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

I have an `UpdatePanel` with two `HiddenField` elements to determine which `UserControl` to swap into the `PlaceHolder` element.  On initial load, one is placed in (this works fine).  There are two buttons, and depending on which one is clicked, a `PostBack` occurs and is supposed to be swapping in the selected control.

When a button is clicked, the `PostBack` occurs, but in the network call, I do not see any `HTML` being returned, and nothing renders on the page, obviously.  I don't know too much about `ASP.NET` and search results have yet to lead me to a solution, or a proper how-to that works for me.

**Update Panel**

```
<!-- Update Panel -->
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="PendingApprovalList" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Page Navigation Bar -->
        <div style="margin-top: 100px;">
            <!-- Secret Sauce -->
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_onChartsPage" runat="server" value="true" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_onTablesPage" runat="server" value="false" />

            <!-- Navigation Clickables -->
            <a ID="ChartsTab" class="googleAnalyticsNav" runat="server" onserverclick="ChartsClicked">Chart View</a>
            <a ID="TablesTab" class="googleAnalyticsNav" runat="server" onserverclick="TablesClicked">Table View</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Page Content PlaceHolder -->
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="AnalyticsContent" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Main Page Code Behind**

```
    public partial class LocalGoogleReports : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
    //Constants
    private const string CHARTS_PATH = @"~/userctrls/Admin/Dashboard/Local/AnalyticsCharts.ascx";
    private const string TABLES_PATH = @"~/userctrls/Admin/Dashboard/Local/AnalyticsTables.ascx";

    //Properties
    public int CENTER_NUM;
    public string CENTER_NAME;
    public bool GoToChartsPage {
        get {
            return bool.Parse(hf_onChartsPage.Value);
        }
        set {
            hf_onChartsPage.Value = value.ToString();
        }
    }
    public bool GoToTablesPage {
        get {
            return bool.Parse(hf_onTablesPage.Value);
        }
        set {
            hf_onTablesPage.Value = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            CENTER_NUM = SessionManager.Center.CenterNumber;
            CENTER_NAME = SessionManager.Center.CenterName.ToLower();
            AnalyticsContent.Controls.Clear();
            UserControl chartsControl = (UserControl)LoadControl(CHARTS_PATH);
            AnalyticsContent.Controls.Add(chartsControl);
        } else {
            if (GoToChartsPage) {
                LoadChartsUserControl();                    
            } else {
                LoadTablesUserControl();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ChartsClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        GoToChartsPage = true;
        GoToTablesPage = false;
    }
    protected void TablesClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        GoToTablesPage = true;
        GoToChartsPage = false;
    }
    private void LoadChartsUserControl() {
        AnalyticsContent.Controls.Clear();
        UserControl chartsControl = (UserControl)LoadControl(CHARTS_PATH);
        AnalyticsContent.Controls.Add(chartsControl);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(PendingApprovalList, GetType(), Page.UniqueID,
            "getAnalyticData();", true);
    }
    private void LoadTablesUserControl() {
        AnalyticsContent.Controls.Clear();
        UserControl tablesControl = (UserControl)LoadControl(TABLES_PATH);
        AnalyticsContent.Controls.Add(tablesControl);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PendingApprovalList.UpdatePanel(); after loading Chart or Table